# Opening app on receiving Firebase Notification (React Native - Android)

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to open the app on receiving notification from Firebase in React native Android.

I have tried the following code and it works only below Android 10.
Any guesses how to make it work on Android 10.

I am sending a custom key named Super in the notification to make this happen.

```
if (remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("Super")) {
    Intent launchIntentt = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.notifier");
      launchIntentt.putExtra("String_I_need", "strName");
      if (launchIntentt != null) {
        Log.d("Testing ", "Inside");
        context.startActivity(launchIntentt);
    }
}
```

I have added this piece of code in the library code of Firebase Messaging on the file located at ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingReceiver.java in @react-native-firebase/messaging

I have also tried putting a foreground service but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you follow the installation guide? https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage#installation. The feature 'open app on notification click' is enabled by default, there is no need of code

Comment: Not on click, I want it to open automatically as it opens on Uber Captain app when there is a ride. I have achieved that but not on Android 10